# Can the Gmail interface be extended?

Tags: gmail, gmail-addons

Is it currently possible to build an app or script such that it appears as part of the Gmail interface and can interact with Gmail message content?

For a while [Gmail sidebar gadgets](https://developers.google.com/gmail/sidebar_gadgets) allowed the creation of customized sidebars that would appear in the Gmail interface, but these gadgets are now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

[Gmail add-ons](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/) provide a way of extending Gmail, using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) as a platform.

You can create a UI panel using the [widget](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/concepts/widgets) elements provided by the Apps Script [Card service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/). The interfaces developed for Gmail add-ons work for both desktop and Android devices.

Gmail add-ons can react to Gmail message content and also use the other Apps Script services (such as the [Calendar service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/)) to access data on behalf of the user. [Connections to third-party services](https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/non-google-services) are also possible.